# IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2017' ('MQRC_HANDLE_NOT_AVAILABLE')

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am getting below error while putting some data on Reply Queue. My Application flow is I have a MQ Listener(Spring Boot Container) in place which keeps on listening to a REQ Queue and process the data once received on REQ Queue and finally puts the processed data on the REPLY Queue.

In my case, the issue is coming while sending the data on REP Queue after certain number of request and reply flows and I am sure while it reaches the MAX HANDLE count this issue starts coming. For temporary fix, now I am restarting my MQ Listener container.

Can someone help on where can I check the MAXHANDS count(I assume its configured at MQ end) and is there any way to check after how many counts the issue is getting reproduced?

Note: I am consuming IBMMQ and all Queue Infrastructure is managed by the MQ Team.

Error Details:

> Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with
>   compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2017'
>   ('MQRC_HANDLE_NOT_AVAILABLE').

Immediate help much appreciated.

```
public class MessageHandlerImplRCC implements SessionAwareMessageListener {
  @Override public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) {
    TextMessage imbMqReplyMessage = session.createTextMessage();
    imbMqReplyMessage.setJMSMessageID(message.getJMSMessageID());
    imbMqReplyMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(message.getJMSMessageID());
    imbMqReplyMessage.setText(dlmToDemiMappedString);
    MessageProducer messageProducerIBM = session.createProducer(message.getJMSReplyTo());
    messageProducerIBM.send(imbMqReplyMessage);
    message.acknowledge();
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your code.   Are you using transacted sessions?  If so are you committing?  Has this ever worked?

Comment: Yes. It's been working consistently for sometime and suddenly above error starts coming(May be when it reaches the MAXHANDLES). If I restart my Listener Container(Spring Boot Container) it again starts behaving normally

'public class MessageHandlerImplRCC implements SessionAwareMessageListener {  @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) {
                MessageProducer messageProducerIBM = session.createProducer(message.getJMSReplyTo());
        messageProducerIBM.send(imbMqReplyMessage);
        message.acknowledge();'

Comment: public class MessageHandlerImplRCC implements SessionAwareMessageListener {
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) { 
TextMessage imbMqReplyMessage = session.createTextMessage();
        imbMqReplyMessage.setJMSMessageID(message.getJMSMessageID());
        imbMqReplyMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(message.getJMSMessageID());
        imbMqReplyMessage.setText(dlmToDemiMappedString);
        MessageProducer messageProducerIBM = session.createProducer(message.getJMSReplyTo());
        messageProducerIBM.send(imbMqReplyMessage);
        message.acknowledge();}}

Comment: I've added your code to the question - a lot easier to read if you put it there rather than in a comment. Please check I haven't mis-represented it.

Answer (score 1):

To see how many handles one task can have open, use the following MQSC command:-

```
DISPLAY QMGR MAXHANDS
```

By default this is 256. Rather than increasing this however, you should be closing off handles that you are no longer using.

Issue the following MQSC command to find your connection.

```
DISPLAY CONN(*) TYPE(CONN) APPLTAG
```

and look for your application name in the `APPLTAG` field, then copy out the `CONN` value and issue this MQSC command:

```
DISPLAY CONN(paste-in-conn-value) TYPE(ALL)
```

and you will see all the queues you have opened. If you don't think you need to keep them all open, then close off the ones you don't need, for example by using:-

```
messageProducerIBM.close();
```

Restarting the listener has the effect of closing them all off, which sets your number of handles back to zero.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thought.
In code now I am closing the producer connection after sending the acknowledge.

Below sample code:
'messageProducerIBM.send(imbMqReplyMessage);
message.acknowledge();
messageProducerIBM.close();'

Will confirm its behaviour after testing as this issue will come after certain number of transactions only.

Comment: Also note you are doing a message.acknowledge after sending the message with producer.send method call. The acknowledge method call has no effect on a message that is sent. The acknowledge call must be used after consuming (aka receiving) a message and only when the session is created with CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE type.

Comment: @Shashi
You are right. Currently, I am sending the ack not after receiving the message. Once I receive the message, I process the same and the send the message back on the REPLY Queue followed by ack call and finally closing the producer now.

Do you think making the ACK call after sending the data on REPLY queue instead of making the ACK call after receiving the message would be causing above issue?
In my current code I am now closing the the producer after sending the message and ACK on reply queue. Still waiting for the issue to be reproduced.

Comment: No, they are unrelated. As @Morag Hughson has rightly pointed out, not closing producer is the issue.

Comment: @Shashi 
Is there any way to check the number of MAXHANDS for a queue manager in JAVA CODE?
Something similar to DISPLAY QMGR MAXHANDS in MQSC.

Comment: Yes, using PCF classes. There are PCF Samples shipped with product like PCF_DisplayConnections that displays current connections at queue manager. You will need to tweak it for your purpose, query for MQIA_MAX_HANDLES.